# SSL for Godaddy subdomains pointing to EC2 - third party?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, godaddy

Our main site is hosted on Godaddy, and we have subdomain A records pointing to ec2 instances. We want to secure the subdomains with a wildcard SSL certificate, but in the Godaddy request wizard which option should we select? Presumably the 'Third Party or Dedicated Server' option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `Third Party or Dedicated Server or Virtual Private Server (VPS) without Simple Control Panel`, as long as you are not hosting it in Godaddy's servers with their hosting control panel. This is the case as your site is hosted in a VPS outside your Godaddy's account. Please read instruction #9 [on this link from Godaddy's site.](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/562/requesting-standard-and-wildcard-ssl-certificates)

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, our main site 'example.com' _is_ hosted by Godaddy, but I altered the A records of the subdomains 'admin.example.com' and 'docs.example.com' to point to our static EC2 IPs. A Godaddy wildcard certificate, as I understand it, will automatically cover any subdomains _and_ the main site. So we still need the Third Party certificate?

Comment: The wildcard matches only for *.example.com, not your root domain(example.com). But you can make it work for both by using the `subjectAltName` set to example.com, *.example.com - check this link for help http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4649/adding-or-dropping-subject-alternative-names-from-ucc-certificates

Comment: Also - http://serverfault.com/questions/310530/should-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-secure-both-the-root-domain-as-well-as-the-sub