# Certificate validation issue with subdomains of subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, amazon-route53, amazon-acm, subject-alternative-names

I have a current, production certificate with a wildcard common-name hosted in Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM). I've added a `CNAME` with a subdomain of a subdomain (like ....) to our Route53 zone that points to our load-balancer (ALB). However, Chrome complains with

> [SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN] "The certificate is only valid for
> *..." (domain intentionally sanitized).

What could the problem be? Am I wrong in assuming that wildcard certificates should handle any subdomain at all depths?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743652/706421

Comment: In short - the `*` wildcard only matches 1 subdomain level - see also  https://serverfault.com/a/310545/960939

Comment: "Am I wrong in assuming that wildcard certificates should handle any subdomain at all depths?" Yes, you are wrong on this.